# A button blink effect in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am replicating a simon game prototype and I am trying to write a function for a button blink in vanilla js.

Currently I have the following function:

```
function blinkColor(color) {
  let colorButton = document.getElementById(color);
  colorButton.style.background = *highlightColor*;  
  setTimeout(() => {colorButton.style.background = *originalColor*}, 1000);
}
```

I am replacing the buttons color with another brighter color and then changing it back again with a timeout. It works when the consecutive colors are different from each other but when it needs to blink the same color more then once (e.g 'red', 'red', 'red'), it does not leave a break in between the blinks and it looks like it is just making one long blink.

Is there a better way to write this functionality?

Comment: Can you post your HTML also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant code isn't actually in your question.

It sounds like there are three events you need to care about:

1. A colour is highlighted
2. A colour is dimmed
3. The next colour is highlighted

Your problem is that the time between 1 and 2 is the same as (or less than) the time between 1 and 3 (1 second).

You need to increase the time between 1 and 3 so that the colour can be dimmed before it is highlighted again. 1.25 seconds would probably be a good choice.

Comment: @JensPõldme — That doesn't change this answer. You still need to make the time between turning each light on more than the time between turning a single light on and then turning the same one off again. (e.g. change `1000*i` to `1250*i`

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I should have specified that the function above is a callback in another settimeout that is called for every color in an array. I increased the time for this function and it did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the color and use a default one when the highlighted color is the same as the current color:

```
function blinkColor(color) {
  let colorButton = document.getElementById(color);
  colorButton.style.background = *highlightColor*;
  if(highlightColor == colorButton.style.background){
    setTimeout(() => {colorButton.style.background = *white(i.e.)*}, 1000);
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {colorButton.style.background = *originalColor*}, 1000);
  }
}
```

You have to perform your comparison to check the type of color (rgb, rgba, hex...) and if you have the possibility to use css-animation for that, just do it :-)